# Restream from rtmp xtream-codes

Tags: rtmp, iptv

I have an rtmp list which allows me to access one IP address, so I'm thinking to re-stream it using an xtream-codes panel. I'll use the rtmp as source and output it to rtmp, and share my xtream to people.

rtmp source works only in 1 IP address. I want to re-stream it so up to 5000 users can access this stream. I have this iptv rtmp://xxx:1935/live?idu=arabicsystem and it works only with 1 IP.

I want to re-stream it and let many people watch this channel. Can i do it with xtream-codes iptv panel ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: rtmp source is work only in 1 ip address , i want restream it wish mean up 5000 user can access to this  stream ! can i do it with xtream-codes iptv panel ?

Comment: i have this iptv rtmp://xxx:1935/live?idu=arabicsystem and works only in 1 ip , i want restream it and let all people wacth this channel :)

Comment: I assume you're referring to this: https://www.xtream-codes.com/  ? On that page it says "Unlimited Streams & Users (With Authentication)". So just on the basis of that, I'd say the people who sell the product think it's possible to have multiple users when working with their product. If you're not sure, you could always contact them to clarify.

Comment: if i gived you an rtmp iptv and work only with your ip address , and you want share it with your friends ! what would you do ? 
me i want restream it using xtream-codes in video input i'll put rtmp and in oupt will give me a list of m3u and i'll share it with my friends

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what xtream-codes is made for. You will get xmbps incoming bandwidth, and on the outgoing front, 5000*X , so remember that bandwidth provision. Your CPU will also have a significant hit while doing this.